# Control the round of a game in javaFX

Tags: javafx, game-development

I try to write a game with JavaFX, and what impedes me is that how to control the round of a game, i.e., how to decide when to move the next round.

Initially a part of codes in my idea looks like this:

```
play() { // the method inside which controls the game process
    round = 0, turns = 15
    // initialise the other components needed
    while (round < turns) {
        //do what to be done in a single round of game
        //let finishBtn be a Button, and with it clicked the game can move to the next round
        finishBtn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            calculate and show the score the player earned in this round
            round = round + 1;
        });
    }
}
```

However, it's obvious that this would cause an error, since within an 'on action' it's impossible to get access to the variable outside of it, in this example that is the 'round' that indicates the current round number (and is useful for showing the corresponding scores of each round, so cannot be removed). Of course I can make it a global variable that can be accessed within the 'on action', but then what happens is that everything just does't show up, and I can't help wondering if the other part of the program runs asynchronously, regardless of the iteration variable.

please figure out my faults, and hopefully provide some possible idea that can be applied here ; ;

Comment: `it's impossible to get access to the variable outside of it` is a false statement. If a variable if final or effectively final, it's scope will include inside of anonymous classes. I would suggest making use of `AtomicIntegers` and brushing up on what it means for a variable to be final or effectively final.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#:~:text=An%20anonymous%20class%20cannot%20access,that%20have%20the%20same%20name.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to make any sort of software that has a UI, you definitely need to have an architecture for it.
JavaFX can be used in various ways and different architectures. (MVC, MVVM, MVP)

If you are not using FXML, then I'd suggest using the MVC architecture and Observer pattern for updating the view.

Here are some examples of my own: (Mostly MVC)

[1. Pong Game](https://github.com/shayandaneshvar/Pong-Game)

[2. 2048 Game](https://github.com/shayandaneshvar/2048)

[3. Quoridors Game](https://github.com/shayandaneshvar/Quoridors)

Some newer examples with FXML: (MVP)

[1. Polygon Triangulation Visualized](https://github.com/shayandaneshvar/Polygon-Triangulation)

[2. Box Stacking Problem Visualized](https://github.com/shayandaneshvar/Box-Stacking-Problem)